# ReactJS Hooks incrementing value issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

If you create a state like;

const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

and increment it with different methods. Result varias depends on the way I increment.

`setCount(count + 1)` //this returns the correct value.

`setCount(++count)` //this does not return the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't directly mutate the state value,

```
setCount(++count)
```

see this post [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Comment: This was it. thanks for the help.